# npm link <package> error code: 128

Tags: npm-link

I am developing a piece of software and realised that a part of it should be a separate package. Before splitting the code, I decided to try the `npm link` command. I followed the npm documentation to create a dummy package (exactly what the documentation describes - `exports.printMsg = function(){} ...`) to link to and followed the documentation about `npm link`. The first part (symlink to /lib/node_modules) worked perfectly. The second part failed with following error message :

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.1: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t http://stash.grupa.onet/scm/oacc/node04-iconv.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'http://stash.grupa.onet/scm/oacc/node04-iconv.git/': Could not resolve host: stash.grupa.onet
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/lisa/.npm/_logs/2017-08-02T16_29_12_731Z-debug.log
```

Could you help me out, please? All I found about similar errors suggest to reboot my PC (what I did) or to upgrade npm (I am running 5.3.0).

What I don't understand is why a command that should symlink a package is trying to resolve something...

Comment: It seems that the .onet TLD is not even valid. So http://stash.grupa.onet/ cannot possibly exists